# How to resolve undeclared identifier problems

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am pretty new in Delphi XE7, got a project and tried to build it, but it gives error like

> undeclared identifier 'Images'

in the line..

```
(TContainedAction(Action).ActionList.Images.Draw(ACanvas, GlyphRect.Left, GlyphRect.Top)
```

and

> TContainedAction does not contain a member named 'image'.

Please help me to resolve issues.

Comment: This isn't your actual code, because a) it doesn't contain anything that would generate the `TContainedAction does not contain` error, and b) it wouldn't get that far anyway because it has mismatched parentheses. If you want help with your code, **post your real code** with enough surrounding content so we have some context and variable/type declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The error is simple enough to understand. No variable or member is defined in the scope which your code is searching.

> undeclared identifier 'Images'

[`TContainedAction.ActionList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Actions.TContainedAction.ActionList) is of type [`TContainedActionList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Actions.TContainedActionList). And `TContainedActionList` has no member named `Images`. Hence the error.

You will need to up-cast the `TContainedActionList` reference to be of a type that has the member you are looking for. I don't know what that type is because I can't see any of your code other than that in the question. Perhaps a cast to `TActionList` will suffice.

You are playing with fire by using unchecked casts. Use runtime checked casts instead so that you find out if you got it wrong.

```
uses
  System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList;
....
var
  ActionList: TActionList;
....
ActionList := (Action as TContainedAction).ActionList as TActionList;
// now you can refer to ActionList.Images;
```

One thing that is unclear is why you need to cast `Action`. Since we do not know what `Action` is we cannot advise, beyond commenting that all this casting feels odd.

> TContainedAction does not contain a member named 'image'

This error message does not match any code in the question.

Comment: can you explore this a bit more?

Comment: I think I've given a comprehensive treatment of the question you asked. You understand that you have to declare variables before you can use them right?